# links between data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame of this form:

```
        C1    C2   C3 support
1      {A}   {B} <NA>    1.00
2      {D}   {A} <NA>    0.50
3      {F}   {A} <NA>    0.30
4      {D}   {F}  {A}    0.75
5    {B,F}   {A} <NA>    0.50
6      {D} {B,F}  {A}    0.25
```

and I want to transform above data.frame to following:

```
      FROM    TO      support
1      {A}   {B}         1.00
2      {D}   {A}         0.50
3      {F}   {A}         0.30
4      {D}   {F}         0.75
5      {F}   {A}         0.75
6    {B,F}   {A}         0.50
7      {D} {B,F}         0.25
8    {B,F}   {A}         0.25
```

This is every link between (`` `C1` `` and `` `C2` ``) and (`` `C2` `` and `` `C3` ``).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to `rbind` the subset of dataset with columns from 2nd to 4th (based on the non-NA values in the third column) to the full dataset without the 3rd column, place it in a `list` and use `rbindlist` (from `data.table`) to row bind the elements of the `list`.  If needed, we can change the column names with `setnames`.

```
library(data.table)
setnames(rbindlist(list(df[, c(1,2,4)], df[!is.na(df[,3]), 2:4])),
              1:2, c("FROM", "TO"))[]
#    FROM    TO support
#1:   {A}   {B}    1.00
#2:   {D}   {A}    0.50
#3:   {F}   {A}    0.30
#4:   {D}   {F}    0.75
#5: {B,F}   {A}    0.50
#6:   {D} {B,F}    0.25
#7:   {F}   {A}    0.75
#8: {B,F}   {A}    0.25
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(`1` = c("{A}", "{D}", "{F}", "{D}", "{B,F}", "{D}"
), `2` = c("{B}", "{A}", "{A}", "{F}", "{A}", "{B,F}"), `3` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "{A}", NA, "{A}"), support = c(1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.75, 0.5, 
 0.25)), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "support"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible approach. This precomputes a row index vector `r` which duplicates each row that has a non-NA value in column `` `3` ``. It then indexes the data.table with that row index vector and builds the required `FROM` and `TO` columns using `ifelse()` to predicate on `duplicated(r)` to select the correct column value for each row.

```
r <- rep(seq_len(nrow(dt)),2L-is.na(dt$`3`));
dt[r,.(FROM=ifelse(d <- duplicated(r),`2`,`1`),TO=ifelse(d,`3`,`2`),support)];
##     FROM    TO support
## 1:   {A}   {B}    1.00
## 2:   {D}   {A}    0.50
## 3:   {F}   {A}    0.30
## 4:   {D}   {F}    0.75
## 5:   {F}   {A}    0.75
## 6: {B,F}   {A}    0.50
## 7:   {D} {B,F}    0.25
## 8: {B,F}   {A}    0.25
```

**Data**

```
dt <- data.table(`1`=c('{A}','{D}','{F}','{D}','{B,F}','{D}'),`2`=c('{B}','{A}','{A}','{F}',
'{A}','{B,F}'),`3`=c(NA,NA,NA,'{A}',NA,'{A}'),support=c(1,0.5,0.3,0.75,0.5,0.25));
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);
library(data.table);

akrun <- function(df) setnames(rbindlist(list(df[,c(1,2,4)],df[!is.na(df[,3]),2:4])),1:2,c("FROM","TO"));
bgoldst <- function(dt) { r <- rep(seq_len(nrow(dt)),2L-is.na(dt$`3`)); dt[r,.(FROM=ifelse(d <- duplicated(r),`2`,`1`),TO=ifelse(d,`3`,`2`),support)]; };

harmonize <- function(df) {
    df <- as.data.frame(df); ## coerce to data.frame
    df <- df[order(names(df))]; ## order columns
    df <- df[do.call(order,df),]; ## order rows
    df;
}; ## end harmonize()
```

---

```
## OP's example
df <- data.frame(`1`=c('{A}','{D}','{F}','{D}','{B,F}','{D}'),`2`=c('{B}','{A}','{A}','{F}','{A}','{B,F}'),`3`=c(NA,NA,NA,'{A}',NA,'{A}'),support=c(1,0.5,0.3,0.75,0.5,0.25),check.names=F,stringsAsFactors=F);
dt <- as.data.table(df);

ex <- harmonize(akrun(df));
all.equal(ex,harmonize(bgoldst(dt)),check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(akrun(df),bgoldst(dt));
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr     min       lq      mean  median        uq      max neval
##    akrun(df) 274.126 299.9995  352.6557 319.243  345.1165 1680.675   100
##  bgoldst(dt) 882.247 916.4595 1022.4152 962.219 1043.0450 2317.450   100
```

---

```
## scale test
set.seed(1L); NR <- 1e6L; probNA <- 4/6;
df <- data.frame(`1`=sample(LETTERS,NR,T),`2`=sample(LETTERS,NR,T),`3`=sample(c(NA,LETTERS),NR,T,c(probNA,rep((1-probNA)/length(LETTERS),length(LETTERS)))),support=rnorm(NR),check.names=F,stringsAsFactors=F);
dt <- as.data.table(df);

ex <- harmonize(akrun(df));
all.equal(ex,harmonize(bgoldst(dt)),check.attributes=F);
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(akrun(df),bgoldst(dt));
## Unit: milliseconds
##         expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq       max neval
##    akrun(df)  52.91901  58.77635  71.72132  67.36425   72.08575  138.3405   100
##  bgoldst(dt) 908.32926 941.77597 980.96350 979.60482 1003.23541 1139.1633   100
```

Conclusion: akrun is much faster.